# grammatical explanation for "When given all the data on the corpse,...."

Tags: grammar

what's grammatical explanation for "given" in following sentence:

> When given all the data on the corpse, Columbo was able to solve the murder.

Comment: *on* means *about* in this sentence. Columbo was able to solve the murder after he was given all the data about the corpse.

Comment: What particular aspect of the phrase are you asking about? (In general, it's an introductory dependent clause.)